# Как ограничить количество данных в LEFT JOIN?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Есть таблица `posts` и `comments`. Нужно (одним селектом) выбрать посты и по 3 комментария к каждому посту.

```
SELECT p.id,
       p.userID,
       p.title,
       GROUP_CONCAT(c.id, c.text)
    LEFT JOIN comments c FORCE INDEX(IDX_comments_postID) ON p.id = c.postID;
    GROUP BY p.id;
```

Такой селект возвращает все что нужно, но количество комментариев должно быть <= 3 для каждого поста. Как это организовать можно?

UPDATE: Sergey Moiseenko выдал то, что нужно, готовый вариант такой:

```
SELECT
  p.id,
  p.userID,
  p.title,
  GROUP_CONCAT(c.id)
FROM posts p
  LEFT JOIN
      -- тут магия
      (SELECT
      IF(c.postID = @i, @n := @n + 1, @n := 1) AS a,
      @i := c.postID AS postID,
      c.id,
      c.text
    FROM (SELECT
             *
           FROM comments c
           ORDER BY c.id DESC) c,
         (SELECT
             @n := 0,
             @i := 0) x
    ORDER BY c.postID ASC) c

    ON p.id = c.postID
WHERE a <= 3
OR a IS NULL
GROUP BY p.id;
```

Comment: А группировка с какого боку там?

Comment: Записи джойнятся, появляются дубликаты для `posts` (если комментариев несколько), группировкой их убираю .... GROUP_CONCAT сгруппированные записи (комментарии) отдает, что не так в этом? Вопрос в другом, как ограничить их количество

Comment: `HAVING COUNT(c.id) <= 3` возможно

Comment: Нет, HAVING мне вернет записи где 3 или менее комментариев. Если коммента 4 или 5 или 100500 - мне нужно из них ток 3 штуки вырезать, а не игнорировать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не проверял.

```
SELECT p.id,
       p.userID,
       p.title,
       GROUP_CONCAT(c.id, c.text)
posts p 
    LEFT JOIN 
(select IF(postID=@i,@n:=@n+1,@n:=1) a, @i:=postID, c.id, c.text  from 
comments c, (select @n:=0,@i:=0) x 
order by postID) c
ON p.id = c.postID
where a <=3 or a is null
    GROUP BY p.id;
```

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: you are welcome http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/ru/book_row_number_function/page2.html

Answer (score 0):

На SQL было бы примерно так:

```
SELECT p.id,
    p.userID,
    p.title,
    c.id, 
    c.text
FROM posts p
LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT id, post_id, text
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT id, post_id, text, 
          row_num = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY post_id ORDER BY id) FROM comments
    ) top_comments
    WHERE row_num <= 3
) c ON c.post_id = p.id
```

В MySQL, насколько я знаю, ROW_NUMBER отсутствует, но ее можно эмулировать, как описано здесь: https://preilly.me/2011/11/11/mysql-row_number/

Comment: row_number() нельзя использовать в WHERE. Ну, и одной таблицы не хватает для join'а.

Comment: Да, действительно, спасибо. Исправил ответ